# Global variable use

Tags: python-2.7, global-variables, pygame

I am writing a module to condense some pygame camera stuff whilst I am running tests, I seem to have misunderstood how global variables work.

```
def init(x,y):
    import pygame
    import pygame.camera
    from pygame.locals import *
    pygame.init()
    pygame.camera.init()

    camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()

    global cam
    if camlist:
        cam = pygame.camera.Camera(camlist[0],(640,480))
    cam.start()
```

I wanted to use the variable 'cam' outside of this module, but it says it is undefined. Is there a way to define it in the module so it can be used in normal python prompt? Also, I dont think pygame actually initialises outside of the module either, is there a way round that? I understand it has something to do with global variables)? (running python 2.7.3 and pygame 2.7 on raspbain)

Comment: Your `init` shouldn't it be `__init__`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to be importing the module, then you should have a `__init__.py` file in the same folder as your other python scripts. Then, you can put your `pygame` initializing script in your `.py` file. Just lying outside, not in any method or anything. Then when you import the module, it should work:

```
module\
    __init__.py
    calculate.py
    video_display.py
```

So when you do `import module`, the `__init__.py` file gets called straight away and initializes the pygame module if that is the script you put in there. Then if your other files, like `calculate.py` or `video_display.py` use pygame, it will work easily if you call their methods something like `module.calculate.some_method()`.

Hope that helps. Happy Pygaming